# No sound through DisplayPort

Tags: sound, displayport

I can't get sound on my desktop. My setup looks like this:

Graphics Card -> (Display Port) -> KVM Switch -> (Display Port) -> Monitor -> (3.5mm connector) -> Speakers

When I boot my computer on Windows, I get sound. When I boot in Ubuntu, no sound.

I opened the Sound tab in Settings and the Output Device menu lists only "Digital Output (S/PDIF)"

I checked to see if anything was muted. I could not find any evidence of sound being muted. If I plug my speakers directly in the motherboard, the sound works fine, so the issue seems to be that the sound is being sent to the wrong place.

I tried to kill the pluseaudio daemon:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

It had no effect. I tried to install `pavucontrol` and it shows me configurations for `HDA NVidia`, but all of them are labeled HDMI and "unplugged" and "unavailable". I tried them anyways and still got no results.

I'm not sure what the next step would be.

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be nvidia drivers. I ran

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002504sv00001043sd00008816bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate]
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Note that the first driver listed `nvidia-driver-510` is labeled as `recommended`.

I then installed that driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
```

restarted my machine and sound playback worked fine.